# Cocos2d How do I switch scenes

Tags: c#, android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

So I have mainScene and I have LogoScene, I am wondering If i can make logoscene show a logo, then transition to mainscene.

here is what i have

```
    import org.cocos2d.layers.CCLayer;
import org.cocos2d.layers.CCScene;
import org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenu;
import org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenuItemImage;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite;
import org.cocos2d.types.CGPoint;
import org.cocos2d.types.CGSize;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class LogoScene extends CCLayer {
    public static CCScene scene() {
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
        LogoScene layer = new LogoScene();
        scene.addChild(layer);
        return scene;
    }

    public LogoScene() {
        super();
        this.init();

    }



        CCSprite pSpNameText = CCSprite.sprite("img/logo_name_textfield.png");
        pSpNameText.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(1080, 300));
        this.addChild(pSpNameText, 0);
= bingo.getLayout();
            layout.removeAllViews();


        CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(MainScene.scene());
    }
}
```

So I have mainScene and I have LogoScene, I am wondering If i can make logoscene show a logo, then transition to mainscene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitioning between Scenes
[Check here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Building_and_Transitioning_Scenes)

This is what I use:

```
auto scene = SecondClass::createScene();
auto transition = TransitionShrinkGrow::create(1.0, scene);
Director::getInstance()->pushScene(transition);
```

A question similar to your's [check link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638128/cocos2d-how-to-switch-scenes)

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[Race scene] ]];